# Extract data from InfoPath xmls into excel

Tags: powershell, infopath2010

I have around 1000 InfoPath xmls in sharepoint 2010 library.
I want to extract the date from each of them into a single Excel file by using a PowerShell script.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

Get your xml

```
$someXmlFile = [xml](Get-Content -Path $pathToXml)
```

Then you'll need to create an array with hashtables from that xml object. e.g.

```
$someArray = @()
foreach ($node in $someXmlFile.DocumentRoot.SomeNode)
{
   $someArray += @{Name = $node.Name; Mail = $node.Mail}
}
```

Then you can do an [Export-Csv](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849932.aspx)

```
$someArray | Export-Csv -Path "yourexcelfile.csv"
```

Comment: thanks Rubanov, is it possible to get this data without using powershell also?